# selecting columns based on exact string

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1_modhigh_2020 = 1,
                  x2_modhigh_2030 = 1,
                  x1_low_2020 = 1,
                  x2_low_2030 = 1,
                  x1_high_2020 = 1,
                  x2_high_2030 = 1)
```

In a for-loop I want to select columns based on whether they contain 'low', 'modhigh' or 'high' and do some operations on them. My method of selecting columns is:

```
  library(dplyr)  
  df1 %>% dplyr::select(contains("low")) # this works    
  df1 %>% dplyr::select(contains("modhigh")) # this works    
  df1 %>% dplyr::select(contains("high")) # does not work. This also select `modhigh`
```

How can I modify the selection of `high` so that `modhigh` does not get selected as well

Comment: Try `df1 %>% select(contains("_high_"))`

Comment: Simply add the underscores to your matching pattern, i.e. '_high_' and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also use the `matches` selection helper proposed by @Chris, but if you are interested in alternatives:

```
# dplyr
dplyr::select(df1, grep("_high|low", colnames(df1)))

# base R
df1[, grep("_high|low", colnames(df1))]
```

Both result in

```
 x1_low_2020 x2_low_2030 x1_high_2020 x2_high_2030
       1           1            1            1
```

Comment: But `select`by default works on columns, so using `select` AND `colnames` is actually redundant

Answer (score 1):

Using `matches` you can use regex syntax (rather than `contains`, which does not allow the use of regex), here for example the pipe `|`, which is a regex metacharacter signifying alternation:

```
df1 %>%
      select(matches("_high|low"))
  x1_low_2020 x2_low_2030 x1_high_2020 x2_high_2030
1           1           1            1            1
```